# Can't find misspelled file name in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I have been working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I am on Listing 8.10, where I run the integration test for the newly created login. When I run the test, I get 1 error which reads:

```
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant SessonsController
test/integration/users_login_test.rb:8:in `block in class:UsersLoginTest>'

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Is there something I'm missing? I thought that it was clearly a misspelled file "SessonsController" instead of "Sessions Controller" but I am unable to find the misspelled file. I have also checked ln8 in the file "test/integration/users_login_test.rb" and have not found the error.

If anyone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it.

Here is a link to the github repo: [sample_app branch login-logout](https://github.com/rlsaylor/sample_app.git)

Here is a link to the tutorial page: [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out)

Comment: Your error message is not completed. There should be some more.

Comment: $ bundle exec rake test TEST=test/integration/users_login_test.rb
Run options: --seed 43995

# Running:

E

Finished in 1.265267s, 0.7903 runs/s, 0.7903 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant SessonsController
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Comment: What  you showed is not part of that.

Comment: I don't think your github repo has the up to date code

Comment: What do you mean? That's the only error I am getting when I run the test. Is there another command I can run to give you more info?

Comment: update your repo then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Just updated it. The branch login-logout is up to date Thanks!

Comment: Last commit is still showing as 4 days ago.

Comment: On branch "login-logout"? That branch is 1 update ahead of master, updated about an hour ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `test/integration/users_login_test.rb:8`, you need to replace `SessonsController` with whatever your controller is actually named (see the typo?)

In general, you need to make sure your files are named the same as the classes/modules they contain.

For example, if I have a `SessionController` class but it's saved in a `foobar_controller.rb` file, it won't get loaded. The names have to exactly match. Even an extra `s` can throw it off. `SessionController` is not the same as `SessionsController`.

Anyway, learning to debug is an important skill that going through Hartl's tutorial will teach you. You'll get the hang of it in no time.